# MVC3 and EF5: Including Child and GrandChild entities in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, entity, entity-framework-5

To make things simple, I have 3 entities (one to many, left to right):

COURSE -> MODULE -> CHAPTER

A course can have multiple modules and a module can have multiple chapters.

All I have in the controller is this:

```
Course course = db.Courses.Find(id);
return View(course);
```

I was trying to use an include but it doesn't seem to evaluate (this doesn't seem to work: `Course course = db.Courses.Include("Modules").Find(id);`)

So I let it be. In my view, I have this nested List:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Modules)
    {
    <li>@module.Title
        <ul>
        @foreach (var item in module.Chapters)
        {
        <li>@chapter.Title</li>
        }
        </ul>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Will this work automatically?

Lastly, I applied a SortOrder column so I could arrange the child entities. I know that this should be done in the query, but how can I do this?

Thanks! Any piece of information or advise would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

**Course Class**

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Modules = new HashSet<Module>();
        this.Assets = new HashSet<Asset>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    public virtual Industry Industry { get; set; }
}
```

**Module Class**

```
namespace RocketLabs.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Module
    {
        public Module()
        {
            this.Chapters = new HashSet<Chapter>();
            this.Assets = new HashSet<Asset>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public short SortOrder { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
        public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Chapter Class**

```
namespace RocketLabs.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Chapter
    {
        public Chapter()
        {
            this.Assets = new HashSet<Asset>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ModuleId { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public short SortOrder { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your class definition for Course in the question body?

Comment: Your loop is also invalid, foreach (var module in Model.Modules) ... then foreach (var chapter in module.Chapters)

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that! Let me update my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
var course = db.Courses
               .Include(i => i.Modules.Select(s => s.Chapter))
               .Single(s=>s.Id == id);
return View(course);
```

And your loop:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var module in Model.Modules)
    {
        <li>@module.Title
            <ul>
                @foreach (var chapter in module.Chapters)
                {
                    <li>@chapter.Title</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
     }
</ul>
```

As for sorting, we can include .OrderBy() on your query but you need to elaborate what child entities you want sorted and by what fields.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Tried out your solution and this line: .Include(**i => i.Module.Select(s => s.Chapter)**) gives the error _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type_

As for the OrderBy, the Module and Chapter entities have an integer column called SortOrder which supposedly has the values 1, 2, 3, etc

Comment: Can you post the chapter and module entities? Then i will be able to advise more.

Comment: Actually, I just needed to turn it into Modules instead of Module since that is the navigation property. You were right! Can you just update your answer to i.Modules.Select? Thanks!

Comment: Oh last thing, can you give more detail on the OrderBy? There is just a column both the Module and Chapter entities called SortOrder which is just an int. Thanks!

Comment: What you usually would do is sort a list by a given property in that entity. If you update with the chapter and module code then i will be able to help more.

Comment: Ok, let me add the Chapter and Module classes. Haven't built controllers for them though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25882/discussion-between-gdp-and-animasola)